# UILabel and UITableView height when Content change

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout

i want to change scrollview content size height when get data from server, i have one label in top of view and one table view in bottom of label, table view cell size is dynamically change depend cell content. there is my code for get height of table and label height, label height always return 24, and table height before get data from server is 328 and after reload table content return 382. how can get real label and table height? 
label height:

```
let textsize = CGSize(width: (questionLabel.frame.size.width), height: CGFloat(MAXFLOAT))
let height = lroundf(Float((self.questionLabel.sizeThatFits(textsize).height)))
```

table height:

```
let tableHeight = questionTabel.frame.size.height
```

Comment: dose anybody has an idea about this ?